# Why won't my while loop execute its function when the condition is met?

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a very simple while loop just as a test. Essentially, the statement inside the while loop asks if you want to continue. If you input the correct character it should ask you the same question again. If you input any other character, the condition for the while loop should no longer be met, and the while loop should be exited. However, the loop doesn't get carried out even once, and the program is immediately ended as soon as it is begun. This makes me think that there is a problem with my condition, but as far as I can see it is met.

I've tried constructing a while loop using just an integer as a condition (as long as a variable isn't equal to a specific value, the loop runs. As soon as the variable is equal to the value, the loop ends.) That program worked successfully, but I can't get this similar code to work the same using a character as an input.

This is my non-functioning code with line numbers:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
    char word="a";
    while(word == "a") 
    {   
        printf("\ntest. enter a to continue");
        scanf("%c", &word);
    }
}
```

What I expect:

```
test. enter a to continue
```

and after I enter "a" the same statement should repeat, and the program should end if anything else is entered

What I actually get:

```
--------------------------------
Process exited after 0.6154 seconds with return value 4210688
Press any key to continue . . .
```

That is what I get from any successful program after it has completed, but with the outputs I want above the dotted line. In this case, there are no outputs above the dotted line, meaning the program finished with no outputs at all.

I have no error messages, but I do have these warning messages:

```
[Warning] initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast (line 5)
[Warning] comparison between pointer and integer  (line 6)
```

Comment: word is a char, and "a" is a string. Try 'a' (which is actually an int, but will compare equal).

Comment: At this stage in your C programming career, you should assume that if the compiler deigns to give you a warning, it has spotted a bug in your code that you must fix — it knows a lot more about C than you do. After some years, you might decide you can get away with ignoring some of the more arcane warnings (perhaps; I've only been coding in C for 30+ years and I rarely take that risk), but I recognize immediately that warnings like those you show are significant and must be fixed before running the code. (I mostly use GCC and normally use `-Werror` so that any warning is treated like an error.)

Comment: You will probably need to use `" %c"` (with a space before the `%`) in the `scanf()` once you get the program to loop at all.  That will skip over newlines; as written, if you type `a` (and return), the loop will stop when `scanf()` reads the return (newline) character.  The blank skips white space such a blank, tabs and newlines.

Answer (score 2):

Those warnings are not just warnings - they are the reasons your program doesn't work. Change `"a"` to `'a'` in both places in your program to use character literals instead of strings and you'll be set.

Answer (score 0):

To compare strings is better to use [strcmp](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm).

**EDIT**

To compare strings is *generally* better to use [strcmp](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm).

This code explains how to use it in the specific case asked by the OP:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
   const char *initial_word = "a";
   char next_word [] = "b";

   const char *compare = "a";
   int condition = strcmp(initial_word, compare); //return 0 -> true

   while(condition == 0)
   {
        printf("Test: enter a to continue: \t");
        scanf("%s", next_word);

        if (strcmp(next_word, compare) != 0) condition = 1;
   }

}
```

Comment: OP isn't trying to compare strings.

Comment: is comparing chars. Which strcmp does.

Comment: No: `strcmp()` compares null-terminated byte strings (NTBS).  The variable `word` is a single character; it is not an NTBS.  You'd have to recommend a number of other changes before this became a sufficiently useful answer.

Comment: Good point. I did it. Please remove downvote.